# .NET 6 best way to differentiate a route in the same controller class

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, .net-6.0

I have an API controller say TestController.

I have the following route definition: api/[controller] on class level and I can call the default get method as follows: .../api/test

I want to have another method in the same controller, I also want to call it with Get and the link should be as follows: .../api/test-abc

What is the best way to differentiate this second method within the same controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For test-abc, you can configure the `Route` attribute as `~/api/test-abc` to override the controller base route. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) for details.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
  public IActionResult Get() 
  {
    // ...
  }

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("~/api/test-abc")]
  public IActionResult GetAbc()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This approach changes only the URL of the "test-abc"-action; all other actions of the controller use the base URL configured on class level.

Answer (score 2):

In .Net 6 by following **Minimal API's**

```
app.MapGet("api/test", () =>
{
 
    return "";
});
app.MapGet("api/test-abc", () =>
{
    return "";
});
```

By following **Traditional Method**

```
[Route("api")]
 public class TestController : ControllerBase
  { 
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public IActionResult Get() 
     {
       // ...
        return Ok();
     }

   [HttpGet("test-abc")]
    public IActionResult GetAbc()
     {
      // ...
        return Ok();
     }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can by defining the controllers route template like as below:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
   ...
}
```

So you can define a method like:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/Test/Index")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Foo.Bar();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/Test/Index2")]
public IActionResult Index2()
{
    return Foo.Bar2();
}


[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index3()
{
    return Foo.Bar3();
}
```

You can call it by `../api/test/index2` to use the method `Index2` or `../api/test` to use `Index3`.

This is for the standardized way to do, in your case you would use `-` instead of `/` at the `Route("...")` attribute.

If you use `-` you need to call `../api/test-index2`

For further information take a look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis).